# Dash app-folders

Tags: directory, unity-dash, dconf

recently, I reinstalled 4 of my PC under Focal Ubuntu 20.04.3 properly (from 0, nothing). 2 are completly OK, but 2 have a strange behaviour with the dash when I want to manage apps in folders.
The way to do is to drag and drop icons with themselves. The first time to do this, create a folder ; then, you can drag and drop others icons in this folder, and you can even rename the folder.
Everything is OK on 2 of my PC ; but on the 2 others... I can do the same, but when I restart them, folders have disappeared, apps icons are alone (normal as initial situation).
The problem is that dconf doesn't record the parameter of org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folder-children. Each time I restart my PC, the personal values are reseted (with only Utilities and YaST folders), but in org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders (in dconf), all the folders I've created are still there.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iFpd.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90fSi.jpg)
What is the problem ? How to keep changes and creation folders in org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folder-children ?...
Any ideas ?...

Thanks for your help.
Ubuntu 20.04.3 64 bits
Gnome 3.36.8

Comment: Are all these installation "fresh" installations, or are they upgrades from an older version?

Comment: No, really fresh installations, from nothing before.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same exact issue.   Ubuntu 22.04.  it *SEEMS* that this may be Active Directory related.   My AD users lose the app-folders everytime they logout/login (even though they are still there via dconf).   A standard local user retains the app-folders.   Not a lot of information out there about this - this thread is the closest I've come.   I'm stumped.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1242063)